# Position of notification window at the bottom right corner

Tags: c#, wpf, window-position

I've got a problem with positioning a window. The window is not my main window. I want to position the window to the bottom right corner of my working area above a taskbar.

I have following code:

```
public partial class NotificationWindow : Window
{
    public NotificationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Rect desktopWorkingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - Width;
        Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - Height;
    }
}
```

And unwanted result of that code:

[image]

I want to have the notification window a little higher above the taskbar.
I think my code should work but it does not.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Add an offset or find out task-bar's size - https://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/find-out-size-and-position-of-the-taskbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this with satisfactory result.

```
double width = 375;
double height = 275;

Window w = new Window();
w.Width = width;
w.Height = height;
w.Left = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth - width;
w.Top = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight - height;

w.ShowDialog();
```